# Directory and Filename Concatenating does NOT work

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working in Netbeans IDE.

What I want to do is:

1. Get The directory of the Current Java Application (Ex: "F:\PadhooWorld")
2. Join a file name to it. (Ex: "\Somestuff.txt")
3. Check if that File exists (Ex: "F:\PadhooWorld\Somestuff.txt")
4. Do a if.. else activity

When I tam trying to Join Directory + Filename, it is throwing lots of error messages like Path cannot be converted to string etc . Searching the net the whole day, doesn't yield any simple usable solution

Please specify a very simple solution.

EDIT
I have only 2 lines of code as yet

String AppPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String fullPath = AppPath + "\Surabhi.txt";

The First Line resolves alright
The Second line (I tried different variations) No Luck. It is underlined in red. Error hints say stuffs like 'Path cannot be converted to string'..

I cannot RUN the code.

Comment: Please show us your Java code if possible.  Your current question, as it stands now, is borderline too vague to be answered.

Comment: Tim, I have edited the post. (BTW, I am an old VB6 fanatic, these type of   File handling is as easy as ABC there. I think I am missing something here in Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're overthinking it. You can just create a `File` object with the file name you want (the path to the current directory will be used by default) and then call `exists()` on it:

```
File f = new File("filename.txt");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); //Just for debug if you want to check the path
if(f.exists()) {
    //Whatever
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to specify the path as well as the file name:

```
String AppPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String fileName = "Surabhi.txt";
File f = new File(AppPath, fileName); //f.getAbsolutePath() will give the concatenated name
if(f.exists()) {
    //Whatever
}
```

Comment: Michael, I have two parts in the File. The Directory, and the actual filename. I have to get the Directory programmatically and concatenate the filename with it. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: @Padmanabhan See the edit - you use the two argument constructor of the file object to "concatenate" the two parts. You should never use *actual* string concatenation to join the directory together with the file name, as this can vary by platform - use the File constructor to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped!